# Debug Xamarin Forms app with source code

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have been developing my application using Xamarin Forms and MVVMCross libraries and I have encountered an error, which leads to Xamarin.Forms. I thought I will just download source code for Xamarin Forms and debug it. I have cloned git repository, then added these projects to my solution:

- Xamarin.Forms.Core
- Xamarin.Forms.Maps
- Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android (Forwarders)
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup
- Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

I have removed NuGet references for these libraries and replaced references in my projects. Application is building, everything goes okay at this point, but when I deploy it to an emulator, app crashes. Here is stacktrace:

> android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ArgumentException: element
>   is not of type Xamarin.Forms.View  Parameter name: element    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00011] in
>   F:\workspace\Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:139
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00022] in
>   F:\workspace\Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, System.Boolean layout) [0x0001d] in
>   F:\workspace\Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:530
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.SetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page
>   newRoot) [0x000a2] in
>   F:\workspace\Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:414
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.Inte   at
>   md59d637456c2e899bd4a90a05345a07db3.MvxFormsApplicationActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md59d637456c2e899bd4a90a05345a07db3.MvxFormsApplicationActivity.onCreate(MvxFormsApplicationActivity.java:31)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

It looks, like Xamarin cannot find view rednerer for **NavigationPage** class. 
I am compiling with Xamarin.Android 7.0 and Java 8.

Comment: Please include the respective branch/tag of Xamarin.Forms code you pulled down.

Comment: @JonDouglas I have pulled from 2.3.3 branch

Comment: @JonDouglas Right now I have added blank app to Xamarin.Forms solution, replaced all NuGet references with project references of Xamarin.Forms and I get the same error with ContentPage. Is there anything that I should do to make any app working with Xamarin sources? Maybe here is some step, that I am not aware of?

Comment: Microsoft instructions at devblogs: [Debugging Xamarin Open Source Frameworks: Part 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/debugging-xamarin-forms/).

Answer (score 3):

I have finally figured out how to run my app. I have found, that in *AssemblyInfo* class in *Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android* namespace I had grayed out attributes, which were telling application to register renderers for views. This is what I am talking about:

```
#if ROOT_RENDERERS
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (BoxView), typeof (BoxRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Entry), typeof (EntryRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Editor), typeof (EditorRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Label), typeof (LabelRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Image), typeof (ImageRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Button), typeof (ButtonRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (TableView), typeof (TableViewRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (ListView), typeof (ListViewRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Slider), typeof (SliderRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (WebView), typeof (WebViewRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (SearchBar), typeof (SearchBarRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Switch), typeof (SwitchRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (DatePicker), typeof (DatePickerRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (TimePicker), typeof (TimePickerRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Picker), typeof (PickerRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Stepper), typeof (StepperRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (ProgressBar), typeof (ProgressBarRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (ScrollView), typeof (ScrollViewRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Toolbar), typeof (ToolbarRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (ActivityIndicator), typeof (ActivityIndicatorRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Frame), typeof (FrameRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (NavigationMenu), typeof (NavigationMenuRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (OpenGLView), typeof (OpenGLViewRenderer))]

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (TabbedPage), typeof (TabbedRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (NavigationPage), typeof (NavigationRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (CarouselPage), typeof (CarouselPageRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Page), typeof (PageRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MasterDetailPage), typeof (MasterDetailRenderer))]
#endif
```

When I have commented this compilation condition, everything went smooth.